# How show datetime select only in Sql Server?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, join, outer-join

I need show `datetime` when I select datetime only. Because I try to run SQL but show all `datetime`.

Table `Emp`:

```
EmpNo   fullName
00001   Midna
00002   Klog
00003   Porla
00004   Seka
00005   Mila
```

Table `tFile`:

```
EmpNo   cDate                     cTime
00001   2012-10-29 00:00:00.000   2012-10-29 07:52:00.000
00001   2012-10-29 00:00:00.000   2012-10-29 19:00:00.000
00002   2012-10-29 00:00:00.000   2012-10-29 07:40:00.000
00002   2012-10-29 00:00:00.000   2012-10-29 19:32:00.000
00005   2012-10-29 00:00:00.000   2012-10-29 07:58:00.000
00005   2012-10-29 00:00:00.000   2012-10-29 18:35:00.000
```

This code

```
SELECT 
   em.EmpNo as 'EmpNo', 
   case 
       when tf.cDate <> null then tf.cDate 
            else coalesce(tf.cDate, '2012-10-29') 
   end as 'cDate', 
   Min(tf.cTime) as 'timeIn', 
   Max(tf.cTime) as 'timeOut'
FROM 
   tFile tf 
Full Outer join 
   Emp em On tf.EmpNo = em.EmpNo
Group By 
   em.EmpNo,tf.cDate
Order By 
   'EmpNo'
```

returns this result:

```
EmpNo   cDate                     timeIn                     timeOut
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
00001   2012-10-21 00:00:00.000   2012-10-21 07:22:00.000    2012-10-21 17:35:00.000
00001   2012-10-24 00:00:00.000   2012-10-24 07:30:00.000    2012-10-24 19:00:00.000
00001   2012-10-29 00:00:00.000   2012-10-29 07:52:00.000    2012-10-29 19:00:00.000
00002   2012-10-25 00:00:00.000   2012-10-25 07:58:00.000    2012-10-25 18:35:00.000
00002   2012-10-22 00:00:00.000   2012-10-22 08:04:00.000    2012-10-22 17:55:00.000
00002   2012-10-24 00:00:00.000   2012-10-24 08:00:00.000    2012-10-24 18:45:00.000
00002   2012-10-29 00:00:00.000   2012-10-29 07:40:00.000    2012-10-29 19:32:00.000
00003   2012-10-29 00:00:00.000   NULL                       NULL
00004   2012-10-29 00:00:00.000   NULL                       NULL
00005   2012-10-28 00:00:00.000   2012-10-28 07:30:00.000    2012-10-28 19:20:00.000
00005   2012-10-27 00:00:00.000   2012-10-27 07:38:00.000    2012-10-27 19:30:00.000
00005   2012-10-29 00:00:00.000   2012-10-29 07:58:00.000    2012-10-29 18:35:00.000
```

But I need this result:

I select date ex. `2012-10-29` then I need to show all rows with `2012-10-29` only.

But some `Empno` don't have data in `2012-10-29` it's set NULL.

```
EmpNo   cDate                     timeIn                     timeOut
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
00001   2012-10-29 00:00:00.000   2012-10-29 07:52:00.000    2012-10-29 19:00:00.000
00002   2012-10-29 00:00:00.000   2012-10-29 07:40:00.000    2012-10-29 19:32:00.000
00003   2012-10-29 00:00:00.000   NULL                       NULL
00004   2012-10-29 00:00:00.000   NULL                       NULL
00005   2012-10-29 00:00:00.000   2012-10-29 07:58:00.000    2012-10-29 18:35:00.000
```

Thanks for your time. :)

Comment: use `cast(fieldname AS date)` to retrieve only the date portion.

Answer (score 0):

how about this?

```
where(datediff(dd, coalesce(cTime, getdate()), getdate()) = 0
```

or, if you really only ever want to look at October 29th:

```
where(datediff(dd, coalesce(cTime, '2012-10-29'), '2012-10-29') = 0
```